# How do I get CrossOver to recognise a disc in my disc drive?

Tags: crossover

I am using CrossOver 12.5.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It works fine for software that is not disc dependent after installation, but not for disc dependent software. I installed Halo on crossover and it installed with out problems, but when I go to play it CrossOver tells me that I need to insert the Halo disc into my disc drive (which it already is). Why doesn't CrossOver autocratically read my disc drive and how can I fix this so I can use disc dependent software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that CrossOver was not having difficulty reading my disc drive but there was a copy-write issue where CrossOver couldn't read any of my discs for "legal reasons", at least according to Code Weavers tech support. They 'would not' help me fix this, after I paid $59.99 for their product (which I purchased to run disc software for school). CrossOver is a joke and their tech support is laughable. I ended up cancelling CrossOver and buying a refurbished desktop with Windows 7 so I could use my 'MedLook4' and 'Encoder Pro' for school. I can also now play Halo.